# Фон в полоску под наклоном без использования картинок

Tags: html, css

Приветствую всех вошедших

Охота на сайте сделать фон в полоску под наклоном, [сейчас полно таких](http://www.stripemania.com/) . То ли гугл днем у меня не ищет, вообщем не могу найти как такое сделать НЕ картинкой. Охота, что бы картинка не использовалась вообще. Может ли кто подсказать набор заклинаний для гугления, или привести пример, как сделать этот самый полосатый фон.

Comment: `CSS3` градиент.

Comment: мм.. градиент он же получиться с таким плавным переходом?

Comment: Необязательно. Градиент это смесь несколько цветов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Хороший сайт для создание градиента](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Comment: Об этом сайте я в курсе. Получается ничего лучше пока нет?

Comment: если хотите во все браузеры ставьте картинку делаете ее маленького размера и все будет ок. Вот как бывает заказчики морочат голову: http://katushasochi.ru/ вроде и без полосок но деталей графики... лучше картинки пока не придумали. градиент хорошо но кода много всегда надо писать и под все браузеры заморачиваться.

Answer (score 4):

Вот тут есть на что посмотреть и чему поучиться по вашей теме:
[CSS3 Patterns Gallery](http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/)

Answer (score 1):

Можете посмотреть как это реализовано в Bootstrap'e - Progress Bars Striped.

[Bootstrap Progress Bars](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress-striped)