# Диагональный верстка сайта с меню

Tags: вёрстка

[image: картинка]

Подскажите как сверстать такой дизайн?

Comment: при помощи css и html. Покажите как Вы пробовали решить проблему(покажите Ваш код) и уточните в чем именно у Вас проблема.

Comment: я такую верстку первый раз делаю ,пока трудновато! а вы что посоветуете?

Comment: изучить основы верстки многоуровневого меню и о том как сделать фон блоку картинкой. Вы так и не назвали **реальную проблему**.  *трудновато решить* не есть проблема.

Comment: проблема в том что не знаю как поставить эти диагональные углы

Comment: http://prntscr.com/azazik самый простой вариант - фон сделайте картинкой и меняйте фон пункта меню при событии(наведении или переключении страницы).

Comment: Посмотрите обсуждения на этом сайте: - [текст под углом](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/517002/) - [наклонный фон](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/216723/) - [другие вопросы о фоне](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В целом работает, но внимательнее с магическими числами.
Как лучше сделать (если без svg), не знаю.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 2em;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(
    116deg,
    black 0, black 18.5em,
    antiquewhite 18.5em, antiquewhite 31em,
    white 31em, white 35em,
    silver 35em, silver 100%
  );
  padding-left: 5em;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.categories, .subcategories {
  float: left;
  margin: 1em;
  width: 10em;
}

.categories a, .subcategories a {
  color: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.categories {
  color: white;
}

.subcategories {
  padding-left: 5em; /* надо знать число элементов */
}

.subcategories div {
  margin-left: -1em;
}

.categories .active {
  color: black;
}

.categories .active:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 21em;
  height: 2em;
  z-index: -1;
  background: antiquewhite;
}
```

```html
<div class=categories>
  <div><a href=#>Категория один</a></div>
  <div><a href=#>Категория два</a></div>
  <div class=active><a>Категория три</a></div>
  <div><a href=#>Категория четыре</a></div>
  <div><a href=#>Категория пять</a></div>
</div>

<div class=subcategories>
  <div><a href=#>Подкатегория один</a>
    <div><a href=#>Подкатегория два</a>
      <div><a href=#>Подкатегория три</a>
        <div><a href=#>Подкатегория четыре</a>
          <div><a href=#>Подкатегория пять</a>
  </div></div></div></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: А от любителя ставить минусы хотелось бы увидеть его решение.

Answer (score 0):

Clip-path если быстро, но там много подводных камней, будет нагрузка с отрисовкой. Лучше svg

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: clip-path обрезает визуальное предстваление фигуры. Изменить выравнивание текста он не поможет.